# How to set Uppercase character is equal a lower characters, PHP

Tags: php

I make function for count duplicate character in a text , I have problem with Uppercase and lowercase character , the Uppercase not count because is not the same with lowercase , my question is , how do I count Uppercase character to?

```
    <?php
function fillCharCounts($str, $count) 
{ 
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) 
        $count[ord($str[$i])]++; 

    for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i++) 
        if($count[$i] > 1) 
            echo chr($i) . " " .  
                         ($count[$i]) . "\n"; 
} 

function printDups($str) 
{ 
    $count = array(); 
    for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i++) 
    $count[$i] = 0; 
    fillCharCounts($str, $count); 


} 

$str = "Nama saya Adhi Dewandaru"; 
$str = preg_replace("/([^A-Za-z])/","",$str); 

printDups($str);
```

But the output always show

```
 a 6
 d 2
```

Expected output is

```
a 7
d 3
```

Comment: Why not use `strtolower`. 
`$count[ord(strtolower($str[$i]))]++;`

Comment: @UmairKhan thanks for the answer , but this show a d n , but i just want a d character, is that any solution to avoid "n" ?

Comment: Well, sorry but the question didn't mention that you only want 'a', and 'd'.

Comment: Alternative: `array_count_values(str_split(strtolower($str)))`

Comment: Why don't you want `n`? it's a duplicate as there is an `N` and an `n` in `$str`.

Comment: @Progrock you're totally right - just need to add `array_filter` to remove non-duplicates. Was going to post earlier but got called away...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

update this function only

```
function fillCharCounts($str, $count) 
{ 
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) 
    $count[ord(strtolower($str[$i]))]++; 

for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i++) 
    if(($count[$i] > 1 && $i == '097' || $i == '100'))
        echo chr($i) . " " .  
                     ($count[$i]) . "\n"; 
  }
```

output will be

```
a 7 d 3
```

Comment: thats great answer , but i dont want "n" to show  just a and d

Comment: wow thanks , thats work , can u explain me mean if(($count[$i] > 1 && $i == '097' || $i == '100')) ?

Comment: 97 and 100 are ascii values of a and d. so you can compare these if you need only these two

Comment: You can convert the string to lowercase before iterating. It would be a more optimized approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is much more readily solved by converting the string to lower-case using [`strtolower`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php), splitting it into single characters using [`str_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split) and then counting the values using [`array_count_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php), finally filtering out the non-duplicates with [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter):

```
$str = "Nama saya Adhi Dewandaru"; 
$dups = array_filter(array_count_values(str_split(strtolower($str))), function ($v) { return $v > 1; });
print_r($dups);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [n] => 2
    [a] => 7
    [ ] => 3
    [d] => 3
)
```

If you don't want specific characters in the output, you can further filter this array:

```
$dups = array_filter($dups, function ($v, $k) { return !in_array($k, array(' ', 'n')); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
print_r($dups);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 7
    [d] => 3
)
```

or combine that with the previous filter:

```
$str = "Nama saya Adhi Dewandaru"; 
$dups = array_filter(array_count_values(str_split(strtolower($str))), function ($v, $k) { return $v > 1 && !in_array($k, array(' ', 'n')); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
print_r($dups);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 7
    [d] => 3
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/oLPp4)

Comment: Or filter before the strtolower as the OP has.

Comment: @Progrock I think a straight string comparison will be more efficient than a regex replace.